# Versionized URLs in nginx for multiple FastCGI ASP.NET Mono Backends

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, servicestack, fastcgi

I'm planning to have multiple ASP.NET applications running with FastCGI behind nginx.

These multiple applications differ in their binaries, and I want nginx to forward requests to the according ASP.NET applications depending on their URI.

The Mono applications themselves are always listening on the root path `"/"`.
I assume I'll have to tinker with the location directive and fastcgi_params, but I don't know which fastcgi_params I'd have to adjto change to make it work.

Sample use case:

- `http://www.server.com/api/1/status` should be forwarded to the FastCGI application running on TCP port `9000`, the request URI should be rewritten to `/status`.
- `http://www.server.com/api/2/status` should be forwarded to the FastCGI application running on TCP port `9001`, the request URI should also be rewritten to `/status` to match the ASP.NET listener configuration.

**The /api/{version} part of the URI should be removed when forwarding to FastCGI.**

I tried this nginx configuration, ASP.NET was called via FastCGI but couldn't process the request:

```
location ~ /api/1/(.*) {
    root   /usr/aspnet/;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-fastcgi-params.conf;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI /$1;
}
```

I'm not sure if my approach with the location directive is correct at all, any ideas?

**/Edit: This is the solution which I came up with. No other fastcgi_params are obviously needed:**

```
location ~ ^/api/1/(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /$1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know exactly which `fastcgi_param` parameters the controller is using, you should take control of them and paste the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx-fastcgi-params.conf` into the location container, rather than including the file, at least until you get it all working.

You may need to modify `SCRIPT_NAME` and `DOCUMENT_URI` too.

Your location regex should be prefixed with `^` and suffixed with `$` to remove any ambiguity (not that that has anything to do with the problem in hand).

Comment: Thanks. It took me some real time to dig into finding out which variables are really needed for ASP.NET. I ended up with this, which is working like intended: `location ~ ^/api/1/(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /$1;
}`